# Curl in spherical coordinates on example

Tags: spherical-coordinates, curl

On Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) the Vector Potential of a Dipole Antenna is roughly given by:

$$A = c\cdot \dfrac{e^{-i\,k\,r}}{r}\,\hat{e}_z$$

Now the curl is computed in spherical coordinates resulting:

$$B_\varphi = \nabla\times A = c\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{r^2}+ \dfrac{i\,k}{r}\right)\,e^{-i\,k\,r}\,\sin\theta$$

$\color{red}{\text{How is that?}}$ And what does $\mathbf{B\,\varphi}$ means at all? I assume $\mathbf{B\cdot \hat{e}_\varphi}$ $\textsf{Here is my whole approach trying to explain:}$

$$\begin{align} B =& \nabla \times A = \left(\partial_r\,\hat{e}_r + \frac{1}{r} \,\partial_{\theta}\,\hat{e}_\theta\right)\times c\cdot \dfrac{e^{-i\,k\,r}}{r}\,\left(\cos\theta\,\hat{e}_r -\sin\theta\,\hat{e}_\theta\right)\\[12pt]
B= & -\sin{\theta}\,\hat{e}_\varphi\,c\cdot e^{-i\,k\,r}\left(-\dfrac{i\,k}{r}-\dfrac{1}{r^2}\right) + \sin\theta\,\hat{e}_{\varphi}\,c\cdot e^{-i\,k\,r}\,\left(\dfrac{1}{r^2}\right)\\[12pt]
B = & c\cdot \left(\dfrac{i\,k}{r}+2\,\dfrac{1}{r^2}\right)\,e^{-i\,k\,r}\,\sin\theta\,\hat{e}_\varphi
\end{align}$$

Which is pretty similar but still somewhat different from the print on Wiki.

Comment: Would you please link to the page you are trying to understand?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It would appear to be [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Hertzian_dipole), but I'll let OP edit it in in case he has another in mind.

Comment: I edited the link right now. It's under 'Hertzian Dipole'. Exactly 'this page'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're taking the spherical gradient "vector" and taking the formal cross product with the vector field. The cross product form of the curl is a mnemonic, not an identity. The formal cross product only gives the correct answer in Cartesian coordinates. Wiki has the formulae for the most common curvilinear coordinate systems on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula). (Bookmark that one--it comes in handy a lot.)

Comment: It seems totally right using the most general definition, but one difference occurs:

on Wiki the $\varphi$-component of $\nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ is given by $\hat{e}_\varphi\,\frac{1}{r}\,(\partial_r\,(r\cdot A_2) - \partial_\theta\,A_1)$. However the Vector Potential of an Antenna (see above) has no components there, only $A_3$. So how it comes the result  $B_\varphi = \nabla \times A$ is a multiple of $ \hat{e}_\varphi$ ?

Comment: @Leon $\hat{z}$ is not a coordinate vector in spherical coordinates. Expressing it in spherical coordinates shows the vector potential has both $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ components, but no $\varphi$ component. Since it also does not depend on $\varphi$, all terms in the $r$ and $\theta$ components of the curl are zero.